# The prop `classes` is marked as required in `FullWidthGrid`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use material-ui-next components, i just copyed FullWidthGrid example in my index.js and i have many errors...

It is a my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
});

function FullWidthGrid(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={24}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

FullWidthGrid.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(FullWidthGrid);
```

in index.js:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <FullWidthGrid />
        </div>
    )
}
}

ReactDom.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

it is a error messages in my console:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined, on the line containing `<div className={classes.root}>`

[see errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM39v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.js you need to pass a classes prop to the FullWidthGrid component with the styles... Too bad the examples do not specify it but I think you can find it in their GitHub

Example:

```
  <FullWidthGrid classes={{paper:"paper"}} />
```

Comment: oh it is good. But in my laptop has a horizontal scroll. dou you know why?

Comment: Not really... Maybe there is something that you should define in the paper css class